# Flask HTML escape value

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, escaping

I'm working on a form which holds already-existent data so when you go for the first time on that page is gonna be filled with the current data, but it gives you the right to update it if your willing to. In order to do this I created a form and I set the value of the form to be the current data. The problem is that the value is not escaped and it shows the variable name `{{ config["SMTP"]["server"] }}`

How could I possibly escape this so I can get the value displayed instead of the variable name?

```
{{ form.server(class='form-control', value="{{ config['SMTP']['server'] }}") }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape it, you need to stop putting it in quotes.

```
value=config['SMTP']['server']
```